# ImportError: libboost_iostreams.so.1.61.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, c++, boost, graph-tool

I am using Anaconda as my main python distribution (though also have the system's default python installed) so have to compile graph-tool from source to get it to work with Anaconda.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 so also have to compile boost from source to be able to use the full functionality of graph-tool as the boost-coroutine library is currently only compiled as a static library (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/boost1.54/+bug/1529289).

I have done so and they have both installed without any error messages, however, when then importing graph-tool in python using `from graph_tool.all import *` I get the error message `ImportError: libboost_iostreams.so.1.61.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

How could I go about solving that problem/what is this caused by?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have wrong `boost` package version installed by conda

1. List installed conda boost package in current environment `conda list | grep boost`, you can see wrong version (not 1.61.0)
2. Search required version `anaconda search -t conda boost | grep 1.61.0`
3. Install correct version with **same** name `conda install boost -c CHANNEL_NAME`

In my case I also have conflicts with this message:

`Linking packages ...
CondaOSError: OS error: failed to link (src='/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/icu-54.1-0/lib/icu/pkgdata.inc', dst='/home/user/anaconda3/envs/py3_graph/lib/icu/pkgdata.inc', type=3, error=FileExistsError(17, 'File exists'))`

Removing `/home/user/anaconda3/envs/py3_graph/lib/icu` folder helps me